# IP over several virtual bridges in linux

Tags: linux, routing, local-area-network, proxmox

I have 2 bare-metal linux server in DC, each one has external and internal interfaces. Internal interfaces are linked directly to each other.
Lets say i have eth1 on ServerA and eth1 on serverB.
If i assing ip addresses on ServerA:eth1 and serverB:eth1 directly - everything working like a charm.
But i need to make virtual bridges on both severs and then bride eth1 on it, so a do this configuration:
ServerA

```
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  172.16.1.1
        netmask  24
        bridge-ports enp96s0f1
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        postup ip route add 172.16.0.0/16 vmbr0
```

ServerB

```
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  172.16.2.1
        netmask  24
        bridge-ports eno2
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        postup ip route add 172.16.0.0/16 vmbr0
```

And this works too. Then i make VM with proxmox ob Server A and pass network adapted bridged with ServerA:vmbr0(eth1), and configure it like 
auto ens18

```
iface ens18 inet static
    address 172.16.1.11/24
    post-up ip route add 172.16.1.0/24 dev ens18
```

So now i cant ping 172.16.1.1 from VM, and VM from serverA. Even in tcpdump on ens18(VM) i cant see any packets come from bridge.

Routes on ServerA:

```
root@wss01:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         5.8.8**       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr1
localnet        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 vmbr1
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 vmbr0
```

The goal is to reach ServerB and VM behind it from VM from serverA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently main problem was in incorrect routes (i used to write it through "next hop" statement, not the interface (as shown in configuration above) 
Arter i have changed routes to the form i show in original post everything seems to be working